# Controls dissappear when changing z-index to overlay a div over a Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, controls, z-index

I've set the z-index of the map to 1 and the z-index of the div I want to overlay to 2. This overlays the div nicely over the map but causes all of my controls to dissappear. The watermark and the scale went under the div and are not visible any more. The attribution and the layers control went totally missing.

Does anyone here knows how to fix this??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: These kind of issues get solved pretty fast when [the concept of "stacking context"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) is understood.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm getting them back now!!